# how to include a github app in CODEOWNER of github

Tags: github

How would you add a github app as CODEOWNER in github so that every time a pull request is raised, it requires the github app to approve the PR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, github does not support. Seems you can use a user token instead of github app token, then you can merge.

https://github.community/t/is-it-possible-to-add-github-apps-bot-to-codeowners/3146